Using ceramic fiber insulation as alternative to type-x drywall on garage ceiling
I'm currently renovating my garage, which has a bonus room above. I've removed the existing type-x drywall on the garage ceiling to install some Rockwool sound / fire insulation in between the truss bottom chords. I'm now ready to re-install a fire barrier.
I am trying to determine if I can use 1/2" ceramic fiber insulation in place of 5/8" type-x drywall to meet fire code requirements. The ceramic fiber insulation would cover the entirety of the garage ceiling, such that the bottom chords are not exposed. After taping the seams with aluminum foil tape, I would then cover the ceramic fiber with 1/4" drywall. The drywall is simply for aesthetics: it does not support the ceramic fiber insulation. There are no penetrations to contend with.
Obviously, the cost of ceramic fiber insulation is much higher, luckily I have relatively easy access to some product at a discounted rate. As far as whether or not this is allowed, I imagine this is a question for the AHJ, but I figured I'd ask here as well.

It doesn't seem obvious that your AHJ is going to give the insulation a pass. (Huge dif between fireproof and actual fire-blocking for NN minutes.) Given that you're going to the trouble of installing drywall anyway, it seems like a no-brainer to just do the type x and have done with it.

@AloysiusDefenestrate Part of the reason is handling the 5/8 drywall. I'm running solo on this project, so handling 1/4 drywall would be easier.

1/4” drywall is lighter but way more floppy. I’d opine that it’s just as hard. Get some helper sticks (post with a cross at the top) or even better, buy a used drywall lift and then sell it when you’re done.

Other trick from my solo drywall boarder is to tack nails into the top plate to support the long edge and then just lever the rest up. Looks hard, though.

Yeah -- keep in mind that lightweight versions of 5/8" Type X are a thing, for that matter
